# WCF Compression and decompression

Tags: wcf

I have my WCF service and client created and i have all my contracts in a different project , not in the service project. WCF service returns list of objects as byte array.At the WCF client, i need convert the bytes to list of object.

It can be done if the service implementation and the contracts in same project.

Please some one help me in my case.

Comment: are you referencing the contracts project from the client solution?

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with compression and decompression, you may have more luck if you revise your choice of title.